# @ViewChild on child component

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to modify the css of a child component ( app-dashboard-menu ) from the parent ( app-dashboard-router )

In dash-router:

```
 @ViewChild('menu') el!: ElementRef;
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  doSomething(){
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background', 'yellow');
  }
```

In component dash-menu:

```
<div class="machin" #menu>
  ....
</div>
```

--> and I have this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')

Comment: You can't use `@ViewChild` to view a template in a different component. Use an input property or a service.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton - that's a shame, thx for your help

Comment: @MohitSharma, no, i need to get element of an other component - so i create only one component from router and menu - thx